# Ligthswitch 2015 screen navigation order on html client

Tags: html, visual-studio-lightswitch

I´m starting now to explore something with Ligthswitch on visual studio 2015 Update 2 and Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 from where is installed the lightswith template.

The question is that I cannot found the **"Edit Screen Navigation" on HTML.Client** and I have no idea where to search (I need to set default startUp screen).

On Desktop.Client I found but on HTML.Client there is not.

Somebody can give to me a tip ?

Thank you

Piercarlo

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML client, the Edit Navigation Screen exists, it's the second option once you right click on the HTML client. However, this only allows you to set which screens appear as links in the top left menu.

To set the Home screen (default startup screen), you should right click on the screen you want, and select "Set as Home Screen".

[image]

Comment: What you said work in visual studio 2013 but not in VS2015 the option you mentioned are disapeared

Comment: No, I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2015. I've attached a screenshot of the solution, projects, and the option I mentioned.

Comment: I edited your post adding my screen shot where there is not options, some suggestions ?

Comment: Your edit was rejected by the admins, in future rather add that to your question.

I managed to view your screenshot on the image server however, so I can see what you mean. It shouldn't do that. I created a new LS HTML project, and one basic type. All screens I add have the option to set the home screen.

I can only imagine something else must be causing this problem, like a 3rd party add-in editing your context menu. Try disabling those and if that doesn't work try a repair of VS.

Comment: I done as you suggested but without any result, can you tell what version of office developers tools are you using ?

Comment: Sure, I'm using the latest version, 14.0.23513.0. That's the full version listed under Programs and Features.